# First answer, then ask

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Lately I see a lot of new users with questions, most of which receive downvotes.
Isn't it possible to let new users first answer a question to get reputation and when they have like 15 points, they can ask something?

This because of the big amount of not useful posted questions. When you let a new user first answer a question to get reputation, they learn how to ask a question. When they get upvotes (reputation), you can see that the new user knows something about the subject. This instead of letting them ask every kind of question without realizing that using Google can be quicker or that they are spending our time wrong by asking stupid questions.

I don't want to sound offensive and of course not every new user asks silly questions. But I think that there needs to be some kind of new filter to filter the spammers/ users that don't ask the right questions.

I hope that I wrote my point clear enough for you to understand my frustrations.

Example 1: There is a user (no names) Who has asked in the past hour 2 question with 7 down votes[closed] and 3 down votes[closed] (Not banned/Blocked)

Example 2: An other user (no names) Who has asked in the past 24 hours 2 questions both closed and and down votes up to -8.

I really hope somebody see this too and that there can be a solution for this problem.

Comment: If we require newbies to answer stuff first, we get loads of crap answers, and fewer good questions to answer as people will go elsewhere to ask their questions where the barriers are lower.

Comment: Who came first in Stack Overflow? An answer or a question? Hmm.. It was a question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thats true, but it is already possible to let newbies answer on question without needing reputation, so there is no difference with now..

Comment: @CTravel Yes there is a very obvious difference, we aren't **forcing** newbies to give out potentially crap answers

Comment: @CTravel There is. With your proposal users would start answering for the sake of answering, hoping to get lucky enough to get the required rep to ask their burning question.

Comment: @CTravel, pls provide some answers and get some reps before posting a question on meta

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that would work. Users for the most part come to the site because they have questions. Not because they have answers. Putting up an answer-first hurdle would, in my view, do significant damage to the site.

Either users will simply not join. After all, why join a site where you can not even ask your burning question? That's the problem you have now and want to address now. Not after some period of time gaining rep.

Or users will start to post very poor answers in the desperate hope of gaining the two upvotes necessary to be able to ask questions. This does by no means help the quality.

Answer (score 3):

As a relative newcomer, this would have been disastrous - I have learnt alot from asking questions, from that, I am extending my knowledge of coding through experimenting and reading other questions (many from newbies).  From this, eventually aftr my knowledge and confidence grows, I will be able to answer some questions and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that SO FAQ can answer this question, because it targets new users and describes them how to properly use SO.

If you look through the SO [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you'll see that first 3 questions are about asking, then several questions about registering and logging in (by the way - you can ask a question without even registering!).

7th question reads "What if I don't get an answer?" (again, this not about "how do I answer", but how I can improve my question), and then only 10'th question is somehow connected with answering: "Why are some questions or answers removed?".

As you can see, from the FAQ's point of view the new user (even unregistered one) comes to ask a question and not to answer it.